# My Pie Chart from Chart.js is not working

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to make a **piechart that get the input from the user**.

*I did what I thought was correct but the chart does not come out.*

When I put the variable **it doesn't recognize the code that I have put in** even though I already have imported the Chart.js using CDN, that they provide on their website.

```js
function buttonClicked() {
    let timeSpend = document.getElementsByClassName("time_spend");
    let breakTime = document.getElementsByClassName("break_time");
    let fSubject = document.getElementsByClassName("first_subjects");
    let sSubject = document.getElementsByClassName("second_subjects");
    let tSubject = document.getElementsByClassName("third_subjects");
  }

let myChart = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

let pieChart = new Chart(myChart), {
    type:'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ['Time spend', 'Break Time', 'First Subject', 'Second Subject', 'Third Subject'],
        datasets: [
            label: 'Plan',
            data: [
                timeSpend,
                breakTime,
                fSubject,
                sSubject,
                tSubject
            ]
        ],
    },
    options: {},
  };
```

```html
<form class="form">

    <input type="text" id="text-box" class="time_spend" placeholder="How much time do you have?" />

    <input type="text" id="text-box" class="break_time" placeholder="how many breaks do you want to have?" />

    <input type="text" id="text-box" class="first_subjects"
        placeholder="What is the first thing you would like to achieve" />

    <input type="text" id="text-box" class="second_subjects"
        placeholder="What is the second thing you would like to achieve?" />

    <input type="text" id="text-box" class="third_subjects"
        placeholder="What is the third thing you would like to achieve" />

</form>

<button type="button" class="button" onclick="buttonClicked()">Finished</button>

<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your HTML does not show us where your own `<script>` goes - it only shows you loading ChartJS from CloudFlare (and you really should be hosting your own dependencies, imo - if CloudFlare goes down but your own host is up then your site's broken).

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` gets HTML elements: which are complex DOM objects - you can't just pipe those directly into a ChartJS `dataset`. For `<input>` elements you should be using `getElementById(...)` and get data from their `.value` members, and it also helps to ensure they're the correct type (`number`, not `string`).

Comment: Your `<input />` elements should have `type="number"`, not `text`.

Comment: **1** your script will load, **2** your eventListener gets regitered, **3** your chart tries to  renders with errors, **4** you fill your form and click that button, **5** you fields get selected then nothing happen

Comment: You have dupe ids, your ids must **always** be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues with your code

1. Using classes to identify elements in a unique way.
2. Using `getElementsByClassName` to select single elements.
3. `buttonClicked` only select the input elements when clicked and does no further actions.
4. The input elements are not known outside your click handler function scope
5. The way you set the `dataset` array is wrong.

```js
datasets: [
            label: 'Plan',
            data: [timeSpend, breakTime, fSubject, sSubject, tSubject]
          ]
```

6. You trying to draw the chart before the click.
7. You are trying to fill `data` with elements references and not their values.
8. I see no need for the `form` tag.

...

## Patching your code

**Still wont work for updating the chart**

```js
let timeSpend = document.querySelector("#time_spend");
let breakTime = document.querySelector("#break_time");
let fSubject = document.querySelector("#first_subjects");
let sSubject = document.querySelector("#second_subjects");
let tSubject = document.querySelector("#third_subjects");

let myChart = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let pieChart = new Chart(myChart, {
        type: "pie",
        data: {
            labels: [
                "Time spend",
                "Break Time",
                "First Subject",
                "Second Subject",
                "Third Subject",
            ],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Plan",
                    data: [
                        timeSpend.value,
                        breakTime.value,
                        fSubject.value,
                        sSubject.value,
                        tSubject.value,
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        options: {},
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="time_spend" placeholder="How much time do you have?" />
<input type="text" id="break_time" placeholder="how many breaks do you want to have?" /><br>
<input type="text" id="first_subjects" placeholder="What is the first thing you would like to achieve" />
<input type="text" id="second_subjects" placeholder="What is the second thing you would like to achieve?" />
<input type="text" id="third_subjects" placeholder="What is the third thing you would like to achieve" />

<button type="button" class="button">Finished</button>

<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
```